# MYSQL: enum field searching with NULL values

Tags: mysql

table person:

```
name
type enum('admin','user','random') NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

When this query is performed, it doesnt return the records that have a type of NULL

```
select * from person where type != 'admin';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null cannot be tested for with (in)equality statements. you need to use `IS NULL`. e.g.

```
select *
from person
where (type != 'admin') or (type IS NULL)
```

e.g. null is "contagious"

```
null > x    -> null
null = x    -> null
null = null -> null
null + 1    -> null
null * 1    -> null
```

etc... it's basically "unknown". Mixing known and unknown in sql makes the result unknown, always. Hence the special ifnull(), coalesce(), and "if null" tests/functions.

Comment: Thanks!  Both answers seem adequate.  however, getting the NULL safe operator into the framework I am using would be a little more triky then the OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NULL safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) in MySQL

```
select *
from person
where not type <=> 'admin'
```